# Chase PaymentGateway iframe causing Multiple or duplicate payment when hitting submit button twice

Tags: payment, payment-processing

I have issues like **Chase PaymentGateway iframe causing Multiple or duplicate payment when hitting submit button twice.** Due to increased activity, we are seeing the iframe is slow to respond. and when users click the Submit button more than once or hit the Back button to resubmit your payment. which is resulting in duplicate payments.

any suggestion in avoiding it ?

Comment: Duplicate charges is due to user may have this issue under certain circumstances (iFrame). Reason is that customers don't see an obvious sign that their payment is being processed after they entered their details and clicked "Submit" button so they click once again. This may create duplicate charges with some payment processors supported by Chase payment Gateway.

Comment: Any ways to handle this case ?